# Appending letters onto a TextField after 100 milliseconds

Tags: android, string, loops, append

I'm trying to append letters from a specific string onto a TextField. This is what I've tried so far. But no luck.

What happens here is it just waits for 100 milliseconds and then displays the string directly.

```
outConsole = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outconsole); 

    int i, j;
    String fin = ""; 
    final String in = "HELLO!"; 

    i = in.length;

    try{
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        Thread.sleep(100);
        fin = fin + in.charAt(j); 
        outConsole.setText(fin);  
    }
    }catch(Exception e){}

}
```

How do I achieve this?

I would like something like this but slower:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ff-eDOGLuYw

Comment: It's not working. I would like some help please.

Comment: The reason it isn't working is that you're busy looping on the UI thread and not allowing it to return to the event loop.  Don't do that.  The correct way to make something happen in X amount of time is an alarm or a handler (Or a second thread, but that's overkill here).  See @IllegalArgument's answer for a good example of how to do it, just remember to stop posting new events to the handler when done with the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Something like this should work:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();    
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
  //update your ui
  handler.postDelayed(this, 100);//this restarts the handler better to have some terminating condition
}
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);//starts the handler first time
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try it out and let you know.